# drush_backend_invoke_concurrent() alternatives

Tags: drush

Release notes for Drush 10 claim that most of the Drush 9 commands will still run on Drush 10. So I wonder what is the alternative for drush_backend_invoke_concurrent() from backend.inc?

Comment: `Drush::drushSiteProcess` seems to be the successor https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/3758/files#diff-55b7c1273b178e1044b509f5331198daR89

Comment: Thank you, I will check now. Documentation suggests only checking Drush:drush().

Comment: "drushSiteProcess should be avoided in favor of the drush method above." so it is Drush::drush(), so I will dig deeper.

Comment: Ah ok that’s good to know. Yes I can confirm `drush::drush` works great ,having used it to write a new command last week

Comment: Do you know of any example for concurrent workers? with Drush 10?

Comment: According to this issue https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/4567 there is no official alternative. 3rd party software should be used to control php processes instead.